Does there exist a locally connected space which can be covered by two non-locally-connected closed subsets?
Does there exist a locally connected space which can be covered by two non-locally-connected closed subsets?
Notes

A space is locally connected if connected components of open subsets are open.
Union of two locally connected closed subsets is locally connected


Take a singleton space. Your two proposed non-locally connected sets don't exist.

My problem statement was ambiguous. The question is whether there exists a space like that, not whether every locally connected space has that property. Fixed the question.

Yes. Let
$$
\begin{aligned}
X & = \{(x, x \sin(1/x)) : x \in (0, 1]\} \cup \{(0, 0)\}, \\
\mathcal{T} & = \mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}}^2|X, \\
V_0 & = \{(x, y) \in X : y \geq 0\}, \\
V_1 & = \{(x, y) \in X : y \leq 0\}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Then $V_0, V_1$ are closed, cover $X$, and fail to be locally connected at $(0, 0)$, but still $\mathcal{T}$ is locally connected. The same example works for locally path-connected too.

What does $\mathcal{T}_{\mathbb{R}}^2|X$ mean? Do you just mean that $X$ should have the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Yes, I mean the usual subspace topology of the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
